# Adding text to paragraph moves neighbor elements down

Tags: html, css

When ever I add text that differs in size to one of my paragraph tags the neighbor elements get pushed down and I can't figure out why.

Codepen: http://cdpn.io/bqJec

Comment: please post your code here, users shouldn't have to go to another site to see the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `vertical-align: top;` to your `.project` css class.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Dphqm